# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x20 in position 108: truncated data

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I want to read an excel file using pandas but get the following error:

```
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x20 in position 108: truncated data
```

Here's the code that produces the error:

```
if not os.path.exists("Raw_Data"):
    os.mkdir("Raw_Data")
path = 'Raw_Data' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xls")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df_updated = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df_updated)
```

The file was exported to .xlsx from a .aspx internal server page.

I've spent the morning troubleshooting to no avail - any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to read, some random bytes? or your excel file consist of data with language other than english? Is there anything different in your file other than normal files with some numbers and some names (in english)?

Comment: The data I'm trying to read looks like a regular data set, with 15 columns and 110 rows. The weird thing is that my code worked before with a previous version of the file, just not this one. The excel file is all in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may solve your decoding problem

```
with open('dataset.xls', "w") as data:
    new = data.read().decode('utf-16-le')
```

so, you can do the operations on the decoded file 'new'

Answer (score 0):

To decode using utf-16, the size of a string (in bytes) must be even.
This `a='abcde'.encode().decode('utf-16')` produces error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x65 in
> position 4: truncated data

While this `a='abcdef'.encode().decode('utf-16')` runs fine:
You can add a space or newline at the end, if the string length is not even. But this is a quick workaround and cannot be applied to all scenarios.